# Proving that a set $\{\psi_n(x)\}_1^\infty = \{\sqrt{c}\;\phi_n(cx+d)\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

I have the following problem I need to solve:

> Suppose $\{\phi_n\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis in $L^2(a,b)$
>    (set of square-integrable functions on $[a,b]$). Suppose $c>0$ and $d\in
>  \mathbb{R}$, and let $\psi_n(x) = c^{1/2}\phi_n(cx+d)$. Show that
>    $\{\psi_n\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\frac{a-d}{c},
>  \frac{b-d}{c})$.

I tried firstly to show that the dot product (as defined in my book for complex functions)

$$\langle\psi_n, \psi_m\rangle = \int_{\frac{a-d}{c}}^{\frac{b-d}{c}}\psi_n(x)\overline{\psi_m(x)}\;dx$$

equals $1$, when $n=m$ and equals $0$, when $n\neq m$. So:

$$\langle\psi_n, \psi_m\rangle = \int_{\frac{a-d}{c}}^{\frac{b-d}{c}}\psi_n(x)\overline{\psi_m(x)}\;dx = \int_{\frac{a-d}{c}}^{\frac{b-d}{c}}\sqrt{c}\;\phi_n(cx+d)\overline{\sqrt{c}\;\phi_m(cx+d)}\;dx$$

$$=c\int_{\frac{a-d}{c}}^{\frac{b-d}{c}}\phi_n(cx+d)\overline{\phi_m(cx+d)}\;dx = c\int_{a}^{b}\phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_m(x)}\;dx.$$

Hmm, I guess I did a mistake somewhere? I know that, because $\{\phi_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis in $L^2(a,b)$ then:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_m(x)}\;dx = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : n=m\\
       0 & : n\neq m
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

but for the functions $\{\psi_n\}$ I got

$$\langle\psi_n, \psi_m\rangle =\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       c & : n=m\\
       0 & : n\neq m
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

Could someone give me a push to the right direction? =) Where's my mistake? :)

P.S.

here is some reference from my book:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the change of variables $t=cx+d$ you get $dx=\frac{dt}{c}$. So you are missing the $\frac{1}{c}$ which results from the change of variables. Otherwise, everything is ok.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! Appreciate it :) Isn't it enough now to just show for example that if $\langle f, \psi_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n$, then $f=0$ and then I'm done with the proof, because the conditions $a)-c)$ are equivalent =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi: Yes, you are right.