# Show a set is othonormal in $L^2([a, a + T])$ - norm of a function composition?

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

> Let $L: [a, a + T] \rightarrow [-\pi, \pi]$,   $L(x) := - \pi + \frac{2\pi}{T}(x-a)$.
>
> Let $\left \{ \phi_n \right \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset L^2([-\pi, \pi])$ be an orthonormal set.
>
> Show that $\left \{  \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{T}} (\phi_n \circ L) \right \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2([a, a + T])$.

I managed to prove that this set is orthogonal, but I have some troubles showing that a norm of a fucntiontion from this set is $1$:

$\left \| \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{T}} (\phi_n \circ L) \right \|^2$

$= \left \langle \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{T}} (\phi_n \circ L), \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{T}} (\phi_n \circ L) \right \rangle$

$= \frac{2\pi}{T} \left \langle \phi_n \circ L, \phi_n \circ L\right \rangle =$

$ = \frac{2\pi}{T} \left \langle \phi_n(- \pi + \frac{2\pi}{T}(x-a)) , \phi_n(- \pi + \frac{2\pi}{T}(x-a)) \right \rangle$

But this $\{\phi_n \}$ is orthonormal, this inner product would equal one, implying that $\left \| \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{T}} (\phi_n \circ L) \right \| = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{T}}$, which contradicts the othonormality of the set.

What am I missing? How should I calculate the norm of this function composition?

**Edit:**
Okay, I got this correctly based on this answer: [Proving that a set $\{\psi_n(x)\}_1^\infty = \{\sqrt{c}\;\phi_n(cx+d)\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792730/proving-that-a-set-psi-nx-1-infty-sqrtc-phi-ncxd-1-infty). However, I'm still curious why my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that a set $\{\psi_n(x)\}_1^\infty = \{\sqrt{c}\;\phi_n(cx+d)\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792730/proving-that-a-set-psi-nx-1-infty-sqrtc-phi-ncxd-1-infty)